# Are there any programming challenges out there for R users?

Tags: r, puzzle

Are there any websites or blogs with programming challenges specifically for R users?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any specifically for R users.  But you'll find a good number of R entries on the [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) challenge.  See this blog, for example:

- http://www.theresearchkitchen.com/blog/archives/category/project-euler

Comment: Project Euler can be used for any language.  I used it for Python and F# myself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about any specific to R, but there are quite a few questions tagged [`code-golf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), here on Stack Overflow. Many of them are language agnostic, but not all.

Another area of the site that I like to visit are the questions tagged [`rosetta-stone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rosetta-stone). Those questions specifically ask for answers from **every** programming language.

Comment: don't forget questions tagged r

Comment: [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) now has it's own Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of any, but you could visit some math-oriented challenges, where you can solve problems in any programming language you wish. One I know is http://projecteuler.net

*Bah*, someone was faster ;). A thing to be added: after you solve a riddle there, you can see others posts on it, many people submit they code, I saw some R code there afair.